# Count user's messages with 1 query for 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join

There are 2 tables:

1. users
2. messages

I want count messages that have status=1 and status=2. Here is what i'm trying to do

```
SELECT u.id_user, u.email, COUNT(m.id_message) as 'viewed', COUNT(m2.id_message) as 'not viewed'
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN messages m ON (u.id_user=m.id_user AND m.status=1)
LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON (u.id_user=m2.id_user AND m2.status=2)
GROUP BY u.id_user
```

But result is weird
[image]

Counters 'viewed' and 'not views' can't be the same. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do conditional sum for this

```
select 
u.id_user,
u.email,
sum(case when m.status=1 then 1 else 0 end) as `viewed`,
sum(case when m.status=0 then 1 else 0 end) as `not viewed`
from users u
left join messages m on m.id_user = u.id_user
group by u.id_user,u.email
```

Comment: Can I use select from multiple tables instead of using left join statement? What is the difference? Any benefits?

Comment: I did not get your question, could you please explain a bit ?

Comment: Sure. Can I use "FROM users u, messages m" instead of using "FROM users s LEFT JOIN messages m"?

Comment: No you should never do this way, its called implicit join and you should use modern approach of explicit join like you already had in your answer.